# Strange Issue with Facebook Android Example

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to implement the Single-Sign-On (SSO) example given on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android. I have followed all the steps as mentioned in the example.

But when the application runs on the emulator a dialog box with facebook title only comes and then disappears.

[image]

I have tried to implement this  [solution](http://myunixworld.blogspot.com/2010/11/android-facebook-sdk-issue-fix-for.html?showComment=1294381258058_AIe9_BGDXca377UlwHOlEr_p3SJo12zdJuK42VkyQyYl2Gqsfx9VfB3w5QY1uqNULDAG_frHqG1hhcgBM1zRquKKCw9_dUIT9Zi38PWDCUdDYqSExi6CNZlNfp4TS4132UXnfwoLaNZ7uF7Tw-kvVMMGzG0QWdZiqE484x-7MLu9lvTNgtRbyNfcPdnh8mEWl7COb_xARXlkG0JcrylLGxt0X2xG62H_8QEwdxmbWA0-Dy1UkB5dmArXYRACe2iIibXU6vy6p-1kR2NcSHRpb0UiPujnTI92m_0KKIEZmB6WeQ5zVrJy9FL8saBsFv_bFoZ8Aq2nM9QyhgqYBIwnjamjTsB85YyPgrw0gMNnaBf7bA_STnhZA0PVUziGp3ghwvamKBoiEnh6oCGlptQAXwLKK1IDQS44V6_ZWim7vtuDSXu5Qj-SOHNuWdU7ttqwAhlwWIPAYIIlrXjHX7fSnUHv98ZOjSVFne93h8lnHhwpTjLMB7Wc-SI#c5442685186348999639) but nothing seems to work.

Please help me on this

Thanks,

Pankaj Khurana

Comment: have you ran the examples that come with the facebook sdk?

Comment: Hi schwiz, i have not ran the example yet but will try to run it now

Comment: Hi schwiz  i have ran the sample application simple. It generates a facebook login button but when i click on it it shows login failed : the connection to the server was unsuccessful.

Comment: did you change the app id in the sample to your own app code and also put your keystore hash up on the site?

Answer (score 1):

Restarting the emulator fixed the problem for me.
And FYI, it would still work even if you do not change the default app id.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked internet on my emulator it was not working. After configuring it the application worked perfectly.